# How to enter backslash in sqlite3.exe using Korean Windows XP

Tags: sql, windows, sqlite, cmd

I am trying to use sqlite3.exe on a computer that has the Korean version of Windows XP.  This version of Windows uses the won character (₩) in place of the backslash character in paths (For example, instead of c:\ it's c:₩ ).  It seems possible to enter a backslash in text editors like Word, but not in the command line.  In fact, even if I copy a backslash character, it is converted to the won character when I paste it in.

Since SQL uses the backslash to designate quotes, I am unable to enter them.  Instead of '\"' I end up typing '₩"' which generates an error.

Does anyone know how to force a real backslash to be entered into the command line on this version of Windows?

There is plenty of software written in Korea, so hopefully someone else has had this problem.

Comment: The problem occures in console window? Try to change font in window properties to TrueType font?

Comment: That seemed to work, Maximus.  I'm not sure quite what I did because the settings are all in Korean, but I did change a font.  By the way, I accept this as the answer the answer, but I think you made a comment instead of an answer, because I could only upvote you.  Copy and paste it and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open properties of console window and choose TrueType font in 'Fonts' tab (not sure for Korean, but they commonly are marked with "TT" icon).